# How to read JSON file to Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

How to write code to read and display key and value from `web_block`, `port_block` and `user`?

My JSON file `test.json`:

```
 {
    "web_block":[
            {
                "url" : "www.facebook.com",
                "action" : "deny" 
            },
            {
                "url" : "www.google.com",
                "action" : "deny" 
            },
            {
                "url" : "www.youtube.com",
                "action" : "deny" 
            },
            {
                "url" : "www.wu.ac.th",
                "action" : "allow" 
            }
        ],
    "port_block":[
            {
                "port" : "80",
                "protocol" : "tcp",
                "action" : "block"
            },
            {
                "port" : "443",
                "protocol" : "udp",
                "action" : "allow" 
            }
        ],
       "user": [
                       {
                                "username" : "toms"
                       }
               ]

}
```

I tried following:

```java
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("d:\\test.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("web_block");
        System.out.println(url);

        long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("port_block");
        System.out.println(port);
```

but it is still wrong.

Comment: You can use a library like Jackson to parse JSON.

Comment: There are dozens of minimal examples on the internet about parsing JSON in Java, both with and without a databinding library like Jackson or GSON. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the following Jackson libraries to your project -

> jackson-databind
>
> jackson-annotations
>
> jackson-core

2. Create a pojo class mapped to your json -

   ```
   public class CustomJsonData{

   @JsonProperty("web_block")
   private List<WebBlock> webBlock = new ArrayList<WebBlock>();
   @JsonProperty("port_block")
   private List<PortBlock> portBlock = new ArrayList<PortBlock>();
   @JsonProperty("user")
   private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();

   public CustomJsonData() {
   }

   public List<WebBlock> getWebBlock() {
       return webBlock;
   }

   public void setWebBlock(List<WebBlock> webBlock) {
       this.webBlock = webBlock;
   }

   public List<PortBlock> getPortBlock() {
       return portBlock;
   }

   public void setPortBlock(List<PortBlock> portBlock) {
       this.portBlock = portBlock;
   }

   public List<User> getUser() {
       return user;
   }

   public void setUser(List<User> user) {
       this.user = user;
   }

   }

   class PortBlock {

   @JsonProperty("port")
   private String port;
   @JsonProperty("protocol")
   private String protocol;
   @JsonProperty("action")
   private String action;

   public PortBlock() {
   }

   public String getPort() {
       return port;
   }

   public void setPort(String port) {
       this.port = port;
   }

   public String getProtocol() {
       return protocol;
   }

   public void setProtocol(String protocol) {
       this.protocol = protocol;
   }

   public String getAction() {
       return action;
   }

   public void setAction(String action) {
       this.action = action;
   }

   }

   class User {

   @JsonProperty("username")
   private String username;

   public User() {
   }

   public String getUsername() {
       return username;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
       this.username = username;
   }

   }

   class WebBlock {

   @JsonProperty("url")
   private String url;
   @JsonProperty("action")
   private String action;

   public WebBlock() {
   }

   public String getUrl() {
       return url;
   }

   public void setUrl(String url) {
       this.url = url;
   }

   public String getAction() {
       return action;
   }

   public void setAction(String action) {
       this.action = action;
   }

   }
   ```

**Explanation**: Data in your json present under "[ ]" is an array, so it is mapped with array list, where as data under "{ }" is an object, so it is mapped with a particular class (example: WebBlock, PortBlock etc) which is having fields of string type.

Now you can retrieve data like below -

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CustomJsonData object = mapper.readValue(new FileReader("d:\\test.json"),CustomJsonData.class);     
String username = object.getUser().get(0).getUsername();
List<WebBlock> webBlocks = object.getWebBlock();
List<PortBlock> portBlocks = object.getPortBlock();
```

Refer the examples here - http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: In the ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CustomJsonData object = mapper.readValue(new FileReader("d:\\test.json"),CustomJsonData.class);     
String username = object.getUser().get(0).getUsername();
List<WebBlock> webBlocks = object.getWebBlock();
List<PortBlock> portBlocks = object.getPortBlock();

Comment: In the object must be placed in any class.

Comment: sorry i did not get what you are asking.